# Inverting a gradient/lighting

Tags: c#, xna, distance, tiles, lighting

I basically made somekind of gradient, by giving a tile in a grid colours, it looks like this:

[image]

Now, I want to invert this, so the light is white, and the surroundings are black, how would I go about doing this? I tried alot, but nothing I did worked.

Here is the code:

```
            foreach (Tile tiles in Tiles)
        {
            tiles.distance = (mousePos - tiles.pos).Length();

            tiles.color = new Color(tiles.distance / size, tiles.distance / size, tiles.distance / size);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry if this seems obvious (meaning you've tried it), but I've done this without thinking too many times myself...

What data types are you working with? tiles.distance looks like a float for example, which means the division will resolve into a float, which in turn means you'll end up using the Color( Single, Single, Single ) constructor rather than the Color( Byte, Byte, Byte ) constructor. This means you'll have to subtract from 1 rather than 255/0xFF, or you'll end up with a value far above 1 (capped -> white).

If this is the problem the following would:

```
tiles.color = new Color(1 - tiles.distance / size, 1 - tiles.distance / size, 1 - tiles.distance / size);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just subtract each color component from 0xFF:

```
float value = 0xFF - tiles.distance / size;
tiles.color = new Color(value, value, value);
```

Comment: That didn't work for me, I just get white tiles, like in the picture but without the gradient.

Answer (score 0):

```
tiles.color = new Color(255 - (tiles.distance / size), 255 - (tiles.distance / size),255 - (tiles.distance / size));
```

Subtract from 255 (Full white)